# MongoDB: Finding a value where object name contains url

Tags: mongodb

We are using learninglocker and I am trying to query its mongodb. learninglocker puts escaped urls as object names, which makes them more difficult to search. I am returning 0 results when I would expect to return several.

My find is as follows:

```
{"statement.object.definition.extensions.http://activitystrea&46;ms/schema/1&46;0/device.device_type": "app"}
```

I assume that this should be escaped somehow, however, am unsure how.

```
http://activitystrea&46;ms/schema/1&46;0/device
```

Sample object:

```
"statement": {
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    "actor" : { },
    "verb" : { },
    "context" : { },
    "object" : {
        "definition" : {
            "extensions" : {
                "http://activitystrea&46;ms/schema/1&46;0/device" : {
                    "device_type" : "app"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the sample document?

Comment: Sure added an example

Comment: `{"statement.object.definition.extensions.http://activitystrea&46;ms/schema/1&46;0/device.device_type": "app"}` returning me result!

Comment: Ok, looks like it was robomongo that didn't want to return results, the query is working fine on command line.